# Woocommerce REST API get specific data about products

Tags: rest, woocommerce

I am new to Woocommerce Rest API.I am done with the setup.I am able to pull all data about the products but I want to specific data like Product Name,Regular Price and Sale Price.For the product name,I tried the following filter...but doesn't seem to give the desired result -

```
get_products($params = array( 'filter[title]'))
```

Comment: You need to change the query regarding your title.

Comment: Are you using a client library for `get_products` to work? Have you reviewed the documentation here http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#view-a-product ?